# Rust actix_web inside docker isn't attainable, why?

Tags: docker, rust, rust-actix

I'm trying to make a docker container of my rust programme, let's look

Dockerfile

```
FROM debian

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get -y upgrade && \
    apt-get -y install git curl g++ build-essential

RUN curl https://sh.rustup.rs -sSf | bash -s -- -y

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

RUN git clone https://github.com/unegare/rust-actix-rest.git

RUN ["/bin/bash", "-c", "source $HOME/.cargo/env; cd ./rust-actix-rest/; cargo build --release; mkdir uploaded"]

EXPOSE 8080

ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/bash", "-c", "echo 'Hello there!'; source $HOME/.cargo/env; cd ./rust-actix-rest/; cargo run --release"]
```

cmd to run: `docker run -it -p 8080:8080 rust_rest_api/dev`

but curl from outside `curl -i -X POST -F files[]=@img.png 127.0.0.1:8080/upload` results into `curl: (56) Recv failure: Соединение разорвано другой стороной` i.e. refused by the other side of the channel

but inside the container:

```
root@43598d5d9e85:/usr/src/app# lsof -i
COMMAND   PID USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
actix_003   6 root    3u  IPv4 319026      0t0  TCP localhost:http-alt (LISTEN)
```

but running the programme without docker works properly and processes the same request from curl adequately.

and inside the container:

```
root@43598d5d9e85:/usr/src/app# curl -i -X POST -F files[]=@i.jpg 127.0.0.1:8080/upload
HTTP/1.1 100 Continue

HTTP/1.1 201 Created
content-length: 70
content-type: application/json
date: Wed, 24 Jul 2019 08:00:54 GMT

{"keys":["uploaded/5nU1nHznvKRGbkQaWAGJKpLSG4nSAYfzCdgMxcx4U2mF.jpg"]}
```

What is the problem from outside?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If you're like myself and followed the examples on the Actix website, you might have written something like this, or some variation thereof:

```
fn main() {
    HttpServer::new(|| {
        App::new()
            .route("/", web::get().to(index))
            .route("/again", web::get().to(index2))
    })
    .bind("127.0.0.1:8088")
    .unwrap()
    .run()
    .unwrap();
}
```

The issue here is that you're binding to a specific IP, rather than using `0.0.0.0` to bind to all IPs on the host container.  I had the same issue as you and solved it by changing my code to:

```
fn main() {
    HttpServer::new(|| {
        App::new()
            .route("/", web::get().to(index))
            .route("/again", web::get().to(index2))
    })
    .bind("0.0.0.0:8088")
    .unwrap()
    .run()
    .unwrap();
}
```

This might not be the issue for you, I couldn't know without seeing the code to run the server.

Comment: I was following the getting started guide of actix-web and ended up at [the autreload section](https://actix.rs/docs/autoreload/). It recommends using `systemfd --no-pid -s http::3000 -- cargo watch -x run` which needs to be changed to `http::0.0.0.0:3000` for it to bind to all interfaces.

Comment: Would there be some variant of `.bind("host.docker.internal:8088")` that would actually work--and would retain the same limit on only the real localhost being able to access Actix? This doesn't work, nor does binding to the Docker gateway IP.

Answer (score 6):

To complete what John said, in my case I had to use a tuple: `.bind( ("0.0.0.0", 8088) )`

Comment: This is not an answer and should be a comment to the approved answer.

Comment: @hB0 I wish I could but comments are only available to user with 50 reputation.